# Facebook Graph API Rate limit Error "#4 Application request limit reached"

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

My app use graph API of Facebook, I test with 2 users that log in and permission relating photo and video,
so following calculator about the number of requests Api I have 400 times, I make a test: I send 10 requests continuously API
after 30 minutes, however "rate limit bar" increate and never decrease and I receive 1 error that is "#4 Application request limit reached".
So, how can I restrict that error or that error never appear?

Answer (score 1):

Make fewer requests.  FB limits how many requests you can make in a given time.  Either request more data per request, or find a way to not need to request data so often.  According to their site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/  the base limit is 200 requests per hour for ever user you serve.  You can request an increase, but you're going to need a reason, and most likely an active user base for them to do it.